# Comparing two remote threads?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am implementing an application which executes two programs in lockstep. Each system call is a synchronization point. An application might have more than one thread, thus I need to identify unequivocally each of them in order to synchronize the execution of a thread from the first application with the execution of the same thread in the second application.

Is there a way to identify if two remote threads are executing the same code or function?

Every suggestion is welcomed!! :D

Comment: Can you be little bit clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it's hard to say not knowing how you plan to do this synchronization.  Are the two program communicating to each other and/or a third monitoring pgm?

In any case there are at least 3 possibilities:

Use an associative container like a map in the two programs (or the 3rd) that matches up

- the pthread thread ids from the two programs (e.g. `pthread_self()` to get the tids)
- the linux thread ids (e.g. `gettid()`)

Or you can possibly make use of `pthread_setname_np()` and `pthread_getname_np()`.  You can use these to give each thread in both programs the same name and maybe that becomes useful in some messaging scenario.  You might also make use of the `__FILE__`, `__LINE__` and `__FUNCTION__` (`__func__` in c99) macros in conjuction with the thread name if you are messaging.

That's my (black box) suggestions!